# resetting tqdm progress bar

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I want to reset a tqdm progress bar.

This is my code:

```
s = tqdm(range(100))
for x in s:
    pass

# Reset it here
s.reset(0)

for x in s:
    pass
```

Tqdm PB works only for the first loop. I tried to reset it using `.reset(0)` function but it doesn't work.

The ouput of the above code is:

```
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

I noticed that they use here: [Restting progress bar counter](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/547) this code

```
pbar.n = 0
pbar.refresh()
```

but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When wrapping an iterable, `tqdm` will `close()` the bar when the iterable has been exhausted. This means reusing (`refresh()` etc) won't work. You can solve your problem manually:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
s = range(100)
t = tqdm(total=len(s))
for x in s:
    t.update()
t.refresh()  # force print final state

t.reset()  # reuse bar
for x in s:
    t.update()
t.close()  # close the bar permanently
```

Answer (score -3):

Try just creating a new progress bar over the old one. The garbage collector will take care of the old one afterwards, getting it out of memory once nothing in the code references it any more.

```
s = tqdm(range(100))
for x in s:
    pass

# reset it here
s = tqdm(range(100))
for x in s:
    pass
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new one. I have some information (description, etc) that I want to keep. Is it possible?